# Why does var List<MyObject>(); work and var IEnumerable<MyObject>(); not work?

Tags: c#

I am learning c# and would like to create a collection of objects and I noticed the following strange behaviour.

Why does

```
var abc = new List<MyObject>();
```

...work and

```
var xyz = new IEnumerable<MyObject>();
```

...not work?

The latter raises the error:

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface.

And yes this is all over Google and I have read many - very complex - explanations which I don't fully grasp.

The fact the former works and the latter does not is interesting and I think it would be useful if somebody could explain this contrasting the two - apparently similar - statements and why one works and one doesn't?

Comment: List implements IEnumerable

Comment: _not work in C#?_ - not work anywhere

Comment: edited to remove "in c#"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEnumerable` is an interface which is both semantically and fundamentally different than a class.

An interface is like a "template" for a class in the same way that a class is like a "template" for an instance of that class.

You can't instantiate an interface because an interface by itself doesn't actually do anything.  You could certainly do:

`IEnumerable<MyObject> xyz = new List<MyObject>();`

This is because the `List` class implements the `IEnumerable` interface.  Interfaces are used to group common classes together without forcing them to inheirit from each other.

EDIT:
Regarding your question, they are not the same, no.  You limit yourself to the methods that the interface implements.  You would need to cast that object to a `List<MyObject>` to be able to use the methods that `List` implements.

Read more:
[C# Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms173156.aspx)

Comment: thanks - so IEnumerable<MyObject> xyz = new List<MyObject>(); - is functionally / effectively identical to List<MyObject> xyz = new List<MyObject>();?

Comment: I am closer to understanding this. Related question - why does this work (in Dapper) var MyObjColl = connection.Query<MyObj>(sql); - MyObjColl is: (local variable) IEnumerable<MyObj> MyObjColl. If this isn't an object of type IEnumerable<> then what type is it & how do I create it separately without using var with dapper? (var MyObjColl = new IEnumerable<MyObj> obviously doesn't work because IEnumerable<> is an interface.

Comment: @niico Objects are never interfaces.  You can't instantiate an interface.  So `MyObjCall` will have an actual type.  I have no idea what though.  Try putting something other than `var` and it will likely tell you what type it actually is.  It is common to use `IEnumerable` because it makes it easier to loop through things when you don't actually care what type they are.  Not to mention that `var` and `IEnumerable` are likely shorter than the **actual** type.

Comment: Thanks - if I don't know what type it is - how do I know what to put instead of var? Can I find out from the debugger during runtime?

Comment: @niico Yep probably, add a break point.  Or just put literally any other class name instead of var and it will likely tell you what it should be in the error listing of visual studio.

Comment: I replaced var with AClass (a class I defined). I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert the type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyObj> to AClass' an explicit conversion exists, are you missing a cast"?! - how does this help me? It still looks like its creating a collection of IEnumerable objects - I know it isn't, but that's how it looks?!